# AWS CodeArtifact - Ip whitelist instead of authentication?

Tags: amazon-web-services, pip, aws-policies, aws-codeartifact

I would like to setup CodeArtifact to be easy to use for Windows developers. Problem is it appears CodeArtifact relies on an token that expires, and I can't get rid of this token. I would prefer to not use an authentication token and instead restrict the repositories to our companies ip address, and control access via policy. Our builds get published to S3 and I control access this way, works great. I've applied the policy condition as a test but I still need to use the authentication token

This is the policy I'm testing with, ip addresses have been replaced:

```
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "*",
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "IpAddress": {
                    "aws:SourceIp": [
                        "255.255.255.255/32",
                        "255.255.255.255/32",
                        "255.255.255.255/32"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Part of my goal is to have things setup so the process is transparent to the developers. I can add a line to `requirements.txt` such as `--extra-index-url <CodeArtifact endpoint> <package>==<version>` and have it work without them having to have an IAM account and setup the credentials.

I know CodeArtifact is new so perhaps this isn't supported yet. Or maybe this isn't the right tool and I should just use S3 instead.

Comment: im pretty sure this is not possible to remove and the access policy is there just to facilitate permissions around who can authenticate.